# ASP.NET Session Expired error when viewing reports using ReportViewer web control in SSRS 2008

Tags: asp.net, iis, reporting-services, reportviewer, ssrs-2008

I am getting "ASP.NET Session Expired" error when viewing SQL Server 2008 reports using the Microsoft ReportViewer web control. I found this article http://balanagaraj.wordpress.com/2009/09/25/session-has-expired-in-asp-net/ which suggests to use one worker process in IIS application pool, but that may affect performance, is there any other solution for this? I tried setting "AsyncRendering" to false already and that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2008 Reporting Services doesn't use IIS.

I'd assume that you have some sort of ASP.net session that is passing variables to a page that contains the reportViewer control.

This seems like an ASP.net problem not a SSRS problem. Increase the ASP.net session timeout.

Comment: I am not sure if increasing session timeout will fix it, because sometimes I get this error as soon as I navigate to the page which displays the report and sometimes I get it immediately when I click on the next page of the report. it is not waiting for few mins before timing out.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at you session state.
I had this problem and changes sessionState in system.web to StateServer.
Note that ASP.net state service must be running on the server you are using for the session store.
Plese see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx if interested.
Example:

```
<sessionState mode="StateServer"
stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424"
cookieless="false"
timeout="20"/>
```